Does the New Testament avoid the phrase ‘you should’?
Strange question I know but I was thinking about how I find it annoying and preachy when people frequently say ‘you should’.  I don’t mind ‘we should’ but even better ‘we have good reason to’ sounds less preachy while more powerfully conveying a direction of what one should or should not do.
So I searched for ‘you should’ in the NIV and found the phrase is not that common. But to my surprise I looked up a couple examples in the Greek and it seems even less common, confirming my suspicion that the bible is actually written in a non preachy way.
For example in the NIV
James 1:5
If any of you lacks wisdom, you should ask God, who gives generously to all without finding fault, and it will be given to you.
Young’s Literal
and if any of you do lack wisdom, let him ask from God
The literal Greek (and I know nothing about Greek) seems to say ‘let him’ rather than ‘you should’. ‘Let him’ seems to me more like a generous invitation to avoid holding someone back, but ‘you should’ often implies that the speaker is in some way above the listener. Ironically not only is the text in question seem to avoid wagging its finger with a should phrase but mentions that God does not find fault when we are given the generous invite.
Is this all in my imagination or am I on to something? Also if the New Testament avoids ‘you should’ is that just the New Testament or is it the Greek language in general?  I am not trying to say we should not use the phrase ‘you should’ or that it necessarily has a negative connotation but I am asking that in general is it avoided for some reason in the Greek New Testament.

This is nothing more than the difference in Greek verb moods vs English verb moods which are not the same.

A good rule in English is that one should avoid the use of "should" because it is far too ambiguous. I remember a co-worker reporting to his supervisor something that one of the clients would need to use tomorrow was broken. The supervisor replied "It should be fixed before you go home.". By should, the boss meant "don't leave until you've fixed it"; the worker interpreted it as meaning "we already working on the problem and expect it to be fixed today". One "should" assigned obligation, the other presented prediction.

@RayButterworth To be fair that phrasing was very ambiguous. If the boss had said "you should fix it before you go home" I don't think you'd have the same anecdote to share. Now admittedly if "must" had been used ("it must be fixed before you go home/you must fix it before you go home") there wouldn't have been any ambiguity however it had been phrased, but having said that "must" can be used for a prediction as well, e.g. "it must be fixed by now!" Of course that can't really be read as a command and this topic is much too big for this comment section, but there's nothing wrong with "should"

I'd suggest that this is just a product of different languages forming the same idea differently; even in English, I think you'll hear "you should" a lot less in very formal speech. There are a lot of NT texts that don't use the words "you should" but still clearly mean "thou shalt do this". James is chock full of them, for example.

@Dottard - welll judging from the upvotes to your comment this is probably an answer haha. Seems reasonobale to me. Different langiages may express the same idea, whereas one seems softer to the ear than the other. But its basically no difference in substance.
